# Laravel Templating nest views

Tags: php, templates, laravel

I cant figure out how to merge few views into one section without Blade.

Conroller:

```
public $layout = 'layouts.template';
action_index{
    $this->layout->nest('content', 'view1');
    $this->layout->nest('content', 'view2');
}
```

template.php:

`<?php echo Section::yield('content'); ?>`

view1.php:

```
<?php Section::start('content');?>
div1....
<?php Section::stop(); ?>
```

view2.php:

```
    <?php Section::start('content');?>
div2....
<?php Section::stop(); ?>
```

Now - it shows only view2

How to achive something like that:

```
$content = View::make('view1');
$content = View::append('view2'); // append view2 to view1?
$this->layout->with('content', $content);
```

Comment: I know you're not using Blade, but consider using it. The nesting is easy there.

Answer (score 2):

```
$content = View::make( 'view1' ) . View::make( 'view2' );
```

This should work. There is a __toString magic method in the View class so when it hits the string concatenation operator, it is rendered to a string. $content will be a string containing the HTML from both rendered views.